# CodeIgniter Api login

Tags: codeigniter

I am trying the build login script but when it run shows me that message:

Message: Too few arguments to function Cliente::login(), 0 passed in
C:\wamp64\www\apiuthomi\system\core\CodeIgniter.php on line 532 and exactly 2 expected
Filename: C:\wamp64\www\apiuthomi\application\controllers\Cliente.php
    This is my code

```
public function login($username, $password){
    if($this->access_app()){
            //$this->db->where('email', $email);
            //$this->db->or_where('username', $username);
            $dataform = $this->input->post();
            $this->load->database();
            $this->db->where('username', $username);
            $this->db->where('password', $password);
            $query = $this->db->get("cliente");
            if($query->num_rows()==0){
                $this->output->set_status_header(401, "nao existe");
            echo json_encode(array("code" => 401, "message" => "Nao existe"));
            }else{
                echo json_encode($query->row());
            }
}
```

Comment: The reason is that the `controller` expects exactly 2 parameters which are `$username` and `$password`. You can change that by giving it a default value ie `$username = false` OR `$username = null` OR `$username = ''` and same for password. Also, please do not show user's password on `URL`, **IF** you want to at least encrypt it.

Answer (score 0):

The error basically tells you that you have not sent any parameters to the function login().

You should send it with login('username', 'password') variables, otherwise it fails.
You can resolve this by adding default values to the variables:

```
public function login($username = '', $password = ''){
```

In that case if you do not provide the variables it would assume they are empty (equal to empty string).

Comment: If you think this answered your question you can accept the answer :)